# Using recv() for receiving a uint32 network byte order number works sometimes and others not (using same commands)

Tags: c

I'm building a client/server over tcp for file transfer (C language): client sends request, server sends file size (uint32 network byte order) and binary file. I need clarifications for the reading of a uint32 by the client

-Client-

```
uint32_t filesize;

...
```

Creation of socket s and connection with the server, for cycle for sending all the files

```
...

 if((recv(s, &filesize, sizeof(uint32_t), 0)) != sizeof(uint32_t)) 
 {
   printf("Filesize error\n"); continue;
 }

filesize=ntohl(filesize);

...
```

-Server-

```
uint32_t filesize, filesize_t;


...
```

get filesize using fstat

```
...

filesize_n = htonl(filesize);

 if((send(s, &filesize_n, sizeof(uint32_t), 0)) != sizeof(uint32_t))
 { 
     printf("Filesize error\n"); continue;
 }
```

The problem is, the client sometimes receives a wrong filesize, even if the previous run worked. Using Wireshark i can see that the payload sent is right, and Valgrind doesn't show anything strange regarding memory.
The server is already tested with a client given by my professor, so it should work as intended, while the client doesn't, i assume the problem is probably there. 
The ifs on send and recv should confirm that the quantity of bytes is right. Any idea why the recv is not deterministic?
Not only that, if the filesize is right, getting the actual file always works, so maybe a problem with handling the uint32 format or the network byte order?

Comment: What is `filesize_n`?

Comment: You have bits an pieces of code which may or may not disclose the problem, but we need a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you.

Comment: You have provided no examples of the intended result and the actual result obtained, you've just told us it's "sometimes" "wrong". That doesn't give us very much to go on. Your receive code mishandles the case where 1, 2, or 3 bytes are received, so you really shouldn't expect it to work.